# Best practice to calculate the Delta of an option

Tags: python, function, local-variables

An option is a derivative contract based on the value of some underlying security (usually a stock's price). Formally, under a pricing model, the option price is a function of `s0`, the current underlying security price, a *lot* of other args (volatility, interest rate, dividend rate etc.),  and some possible `kwargs`.

The Delta of an option is the rate of change of its price with regard to the underlying security's price. In practice, this is implemented like

`(calc_price(s0 + ds, **kwargs) - calc_price(s0 - ds, **kwargs)) / (2 * ds)`

What I want to do is implement `get_delta` as a *method* of the `Option` class  So now I have implemented a pricing model for the option as:

```py
class Option:
    def __init__(self, s0, lots_of_args, **kwargs):
        self.s0 = s0

        # actually there's a list of lots of args, not packed
        self.lots_of_args = lots_of_args
        # actually kwargs are unpacked either,
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def calc_price(self):
        price = ...
        return price

    def get_delta(self, ds=.05):
        cd = Option(self.s0 - ds, self.lots_of_args, **self.kwargs).calc_price()
        cu = Option(self.s0 + ds, self.lots_of_args, **self.kwargs).calc_price()   
        return (cu - cd) / (2 * ds)
```

The problem is that there are really a *lot* of args other than `s0` (represented as *lots_of_args*, but actually they aren't a single arg, but there are a dozen of them), so I really hate to copy them one by one into the `get_delta` function. I need a way to get a dict of the args that are passed to `__init__`. The first thought, of course, is to use `locals()`. However, there're some problems:

1. an extra `self` arg is included.
2. `kwargs` are *not* unpacked.
3. The [doc on `locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#locals) advises against modifying the dict returned by `locals()`, so I don't think it's a good idea to `del` the `self` arg and `update` the unpacked `kwargs`.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You can call "copy" on a dict to get a freely modifiable copy.

Comment: @MichaelButscher it does work. The copy of `locals()` can be treated like any ordinary dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about copying?

```py
import copy

class Option:
    def __init__(self, s0, lots_of_args, **kwargs):
        self.s0 = s0

    def calc_price(self):
        price = ...
        return price

    def get_delta(self, ds=.05):
        cd = copy.copy(self)
        cd.s0 -= ds
        cu = copy.copy(self)
        cu.s0 += ds

        return (cu.calc_price() - cd.calc_price()) / (2 * ds)
```

If your class has some dict/list attrs (or attrs using other mutable classes), then you might want to use `copy.deepcopy` instead (for example if `calc_price()` changes those attributes).

And you can define [`__copy__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) method to customize how copy is being created.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just to copy those "lots of args", without changing them, then you can use an approach similar to [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)'s [`_replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) method:

```
>>> import collections
>>> Option = collections.namedtuple('Option', 'a b c d e f')
>>> opt = Option(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6)
>>> opt
Option(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6)
>>> new_opt = opt._replace(a=74)
>>> new_opt
Option(a=74, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6)  # only 'a' changed, all other args remained the same
```

Then your `get_delta()` method would look like this:

```
def get_delta(self, ds=.05):
    cd = self._replace(s0=self.s0 - ds).calc_price()
    cu = self._replace(s0=self.s0 + ds).calc_price()   
    return (cu - cd) / (2 * ds)
```

Whether to inherit directly from a namedtuple or to create your own `_replace`-like method is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not modify the calc_price method to include a ds?
The get_delta then simplifies to calling calc_price with positive and negative ds:

```
def calc_price(self, ds=0):
    s0 = self.s0 + ds 
    price = ... return price 

def get_delta(self, ds=.05): 
    cd = self.calc_price(-ds)
    cu = self.calc_price(ds) 
    return (cu - cd) / (2 * ds) here
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work too. But since `ds` isn't related to `calc_price`, it may look weird to include it as an arg.

Comment: @Vim True, but most of the other suggestions are even more obscure.
If changing calc_price is not a possibility I recommend imposeren's copy approach, which is still reasonably clear.